# Custom javadoc tags in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, javadoc

I'm trying to use custom javadoc tags in a Netbeans project.  I've added the javadoc command line options to the project settings and the tags work fine when I actually generate the javadoc, but for some reason the custom tags don't show at all in the javadoc previews that the IDE displays.  Is this a Netbeans bug or did I miss a step somewhere to make the tags display in the IDE?

Edit: This is Netbeans 7.2

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem. If I generate JavaDocs I see the tags but not in the popup help windows Netbeans uses.